# QGIS: No transform available error

Tags: qgis, error, ubuntu, proj, transform

I installed QGIS 3.16 on Ubuntu-20.04.

Details on 'About QGIS':

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QGIS version | 3.16.12-Hannover | QGIS code revision | be6cb030ac |
| Compiled against Qt | 5.12.8 | Running against Qt | 5.12.8 |
| Compiled against GDAL/OGR | 3.0.4 | Running against GDAL/OGR | 3.0.4 |
| Compiled against GEOS | 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 | Running against GEOS | 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2 |
| Compiled against SQLite | 3.31.1 | Running against SQLite | 3.31.1 |
| PostgreSQL Client Version | 12.8 (Ubuntu 12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) | SpatiaLite Version | 4.3.0a |
| QWT Version | 6.1.4 | QScintilla2 Version | 2.11.2 |
| Compiled against PROJ | 6.3.1 | Running against PROJ | Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020 |
| OS Version | Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS |  |  |
| Active python plugins | gribdownloader |  |  |
|  | SRTM-Downloader |  |  |
|  | gis4wrf |  |  |
|  | modis_nitk |  |  |
|  | db_manager |  |  |
|  | MetaSearch |  |  |
|  | processing |  |  |

When I added raster layer 'stamen terrain background' from plugin 'gis4wrf', which has CRS of 'EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator'.

And the error message:

---

*No transform is available between EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator and Custom CRS: GEOGCRS["unknown",DATUM["unknown",ELLIPSOID["WGS 8….


proj_create_operations: SQLite error on SELECT name, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, geodetic_crs_auth_name, geodetic_crs_code, conversion_auth_name, conversion_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM projected_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name*

---

and when I added a vector layer with CRS: PCS_ITRF2000_TM,

another but same error message:

---

*No transform is available between PCS_ITRF2000_TM and Custom CRS: GEOGCRS["unknown",DATUM["World Geodetic System 198….


proj_create_operations: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name*

---

and I think it happens everytime, like:

*between PCS_ITRF2000_TM and EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator

between PCS_ITRF2000_TM and EPSG:4322 - WGS 72

between PCS_ITRF2000_TM and EPSG:4326 - WGS 84

between EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator and Custom CRS

between EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator and EPSG:4322 - WGS 72

between EPSG:4322 - WGS 72 and Custom CRS

between Custom CRS*

etc.....

---

when I added same layers with QGIS 3.16 on Windows10, it worked fine.
I saw some similar questions, but remain unsolved.

I don't know what to do, or where to look at..
Any advise?

Comment: You have mismatch between the Proj version and proj.db database version that your system finds. Hopefully you can find help from these old questions dealing with the same problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=such+column%3A+area_of_use_auth_name.

Comment: @user30184 I tried proj library setting to conda one, by `export PROJ_LIB=home/<username>/miniconda3/share/proj` and it seems to be solved..! Though I see warning message `proj_get_authorities_from_database: Cannot find proj.db`
`proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db` when starting, but somehow it works properly.. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when upgrading my QGIS on Ubuntu20.04.

The mismatch between proj-bin and proj-data could be seen in the command:

`projinfo -s EPSG:3059 -t EPSG:4326`

that returned: "source CRS: parsing of user string failed: SQLite error on SELECT name, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, geodetic_crs_auth_name, geodetic_crs_code, conversion_auth_name, conversion_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM projected_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name"

I manage to reinstall QGIS by reinstalling first proj-bin and proj-data properly:

```
sudo apt remove proj-bin proj-data
sudo apt install proj-bin proj-data
```

and `sudo apt install qgis` to finally reinstall qgis.

Note: removing proj-data will remove a bunch of librairies including gdal, that were safely reinstalled after in my case, but be careful...